# Running a perl command in a bash script on OSX

Tags: macos, perl, bash

Ok noob question here.

I have a bash script on a mac which runs a perl command. More specifically I want to run the following on a text variable

```
...

mytext=...

...

perl -pe 's/-\K(\w)/\U$1/g' ${mytext}
```

But I just get -

```
Can't open perl script "mytextis": No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this:

```
perl -pe 's/-\K(\w)/\U$1/g' <<< ${mytext}
```

This way the content of `${mytext}` is used as standard input for the `perl` script, otherwise the shell treats it as a command line argument, which then `perl` treats as a filename to read a script from.

The `<<<` is a *Here String*, a variant of *Here Documents*. You can read about it in `man bash`, in the section **Here Strings**.